# \startcombination spanning multiple pages? (ConTeXt)

Tags: graphics, context

I make extensive use of `\startcombination` for my grid of images and am very happy with what it produces.

```
\startcombination[4*3]
{\externalfigure[http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81P31hUJh7L._SY606_.jpg][vhs]}{}
{\externalfigure[http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/91nE4VCZenL._SL1500_.jpg][vhs]}{}
{\externalfigure[http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51QQSSXXYBL.jpg][vhs]}{}
{\externalfigure[http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51CQ9EKNZ6L.jpg][vhs]}{}
{\externalfigure[http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/91HL7FIOiqL._SL1500_.jpg][vhs]}{}
\stopcombination
```

[image]

However, after filling an entire page with images, I have to create a separate `\startcombination` on the next page to add more images. Is there an option or alternative directive that will allow me to just put all my images in a single one and have the typesetter use up however many pages it needs?

Comment: The source is in pack-com.mkiv, and it doesn't look like it could do what you want. However, the file also mentions that one could use one of the table environments, which can split across pages. But there may be a reason why you want to use combinations? If not, try, e.g., Natural Tables or Extreme Tables

Comment: Oh, if tables can span multiple pages I should give that a try. I'm new to ConTeXt and have just been copying code blindly. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by Thomas, you can use tables instead. ConTeXt has different table mechanisms. Personally, I find the natural tables environment to be most versatile. Here is how to achieve what you want using natural tables:

```
\defineexternalfigure[vhs][width=3cm]

\startsetups collection
  \setupTABLE[frame=off, align={midle,lohi}]
\stopsetups

\starttext
\startTABLE[split=yes, setups=collection]
  \dorecurse{10}
  {
  \NC \externalfigure[http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81P31hUJh7L._SY606_.jpg][vhs]
  \NC \externalfigure[http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/91nE4VCZenL._SL1500_.jpg][vhs]
  \NC \externalfigure[http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51QQSSXXYBL.jpg][vhs]
  \NC \NR
  }
\stopTABLE
```

Comment: The only problem with this (for my case) is that it's not easy to change the number of cells per row. So I'm in 2 minds whether to use this.